# How can i send data to a database from a view in Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I created a form in my Django project, i would now like to have this form interact with a database.

Basically, when the user inputs some data, it must be sent to a database. Note: i already have a database in my django project, i defined it on my **settings.py**, but i must not send the data to that DB, but to a *different* database, since that db will interact with another Python script.

Now, what i don't know, is how can i use another database in Django? Where should i define the whole second database configuration?

This is what my basic view looks like at the moment:

```
def input(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            messages.success(request, f"Success")

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = InputForm()

    return render(request,
                  "main/data.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

Comment: You can have multiple databases defined in you `settings.py` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Looking into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the second database in settings, see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Then you will just save the form in a particular database like this:
`form.save(using='database_name')`

Or if you're using it for a particular model in your project you can overload save method of this model to be stored in another DB:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, ...): # ALL the signature
        super(SomeModel, self).save(using='database_name')
```